# How to move a camera left and right in LibGDX

Tags: java, vector, camera, libgdx

I have a camera which I control using WASD, but I'm stuck on moving it left and right. I've been looking all over the internet and it says to find a vector perpendicular to another you change the x and y round and times one of them by -1. I've tried this in the code below:

```
void camstrafe (String dir) {
    Vector3 direction = camera.direction.nor();
    Vector3 old = direction;
    direction.set(-old.z, 0, old.x);
    camera.translate(direction.scl(0.18f));
}
```

I have moving forwards working fine, and actually turning the camera round, but for some reason this doesn't work, and to be honest I'm not sure what it really does because when I press `a` or `d` (they call this function) the camera just goes crazy and starts turning round really quickly and sometimes going forwards or like a million miles sideways. Anyway, does anyone know how I could do this properly? By the way I've also tried getting the forward direction of the camera and using the `.rotate()` function rotating it 90 degrees right/left then translating it that way but that does the same thing. I'm thinking maybe cameras don't work the same was as other things do when translating them sideways/backwards.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should know that in Java, assigning object references to new variables does not produce a copy. In your code `old` and `direction` point at the same object, so `old` is completely redundant to use. I just point that out since you are likely to run into some nasty bugs if you're unaware of that. In this case, it doesn't matter since you aren't trying to use `old` to track old values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To archive camera movement between 2 vectors use the camera lerp:

```
public class myclass {
       [...]

         private OrthographicCamera camera;
         public Vector3 posCameraDesired;

            [...]

        private void processCameraMovement(){
            /// make some camera movement
                  posCameraDesired.x+=100.0f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                  posCameraDesired.y+=100.0f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }

        [...]

            //render method
            public void draw(){

            [...]

            processCameraMovement();
            camera.position.lerp(posCameraDesired,0.1f);//vector of the camera desired position and smoothness of the movement

            [...]



            }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, in your class, you must have an Animations object, lets call it Anim. In your class instanciation, you must create an `OrthographicCamera` object, that will be your camera instance. You have to give it a value, such as :

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

This `camera` coordonates can be set up the first time you use it, and you can do it with the method `.translate()` :

```
camera.translate(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight);
```

Otherwise the positio will be set at 0;0.

In your `render()` method, you have to use a method from the `camera` object called `update()`, like bellow :

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    anim.load();
    camera.update();
    ....
    game();
    ....
}
```

This method is always running during the game/app you develop. So every time the method runs, the `camera` is updated, and its position too.

Then, in your `game()` method, or in an other method (depending on your architecture), where you are dealing with the inputs of the user, you move the position of the camera, and modify the `camera.position` in it. like bellow :

```
 public void game() {
   if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) { // or A  
           moveBack(anim); // The method to move back
           camera.position.x -= 3; // if conditions are ok, move the camera back.
   } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) { or D  
       moveForward(anim); // The method to move forward
       camera.position.x += 3; // if conditions are ok, move the camera to the front. 
   }
```

When the user is moving, the method to move is called, and the camera position is modified. Each time the method `render()` is called, the `camera` is updated with its new position.

Comment: What would be in the `moveBack()` and `moveForward()` functions? Also, does it have to be an `OrthographicCamera` or can it be a `PerspectiveCamera` and what does anim do?

Comment: The camera does not need to be instantiated with a position. The default is `0, 0` and translate is not used for this at all. Using translate you can do `cam.translate(-10, 10)` instead of `cam.position.x -= 10` and `cam.position.y += 10`. Neither should you update the camera each frame, you update it each time it needs updating. This could be each frame but in most of my cases I just update it when I move it.

Comment: Hello, `moveBack()` in that case, modifies the coordonates of my player. The `anim` object is an object that deals with the set up of the frame, the image and the animations of the screen such as showing backgrounds sprites etc.

Comment: Hello Menno Gouw, in fact, it depends on how the action is set on the app. If you have many objects moving, you have to update the camera position and the background screen at every frame.

Comment: what does anim do though?

Comment: The `anim` object is an object that deals with the set up of the frame, the image and the animations of the screen such as showing backgrounds sprites etc."